# Jquery UI Datpicker excluding weekends minDate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, mindate

How do I make jQuery UI datepicker exclude weekends and also set `minDate` to a certain value like +2 / +3 (excluding weekends) ???

What I've tried:

```js
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 4, 
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
```

For **example** When I select a Monday (like today 10th) and give 'minDate' as 10 , from 24th onwards should be enabled.

Can anyone please help me out? I want to be able to calculate the `minDate` value without including Saturdays and Sundays.

FIDDLE- http://jsfiddle.net/betrob/7DHVr/2/

Thank you

Comment: In other words, min date 10 means today + 10 weekdays?

Comment: can you make a fiddle.?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if my explanation was confusing

Comment: @BetRob, Did you try my answer?

Comment: @Neha I added a fiddle in my answer. Can you optimize the code?

Comment: @ScriptShiva added optimize version !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to optimize @Shiva logic to make it more faster. Hope its help, please feel free to point out any improvements or loopholes. :)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7DHVr/9/)

```
var count = 10;
//Add the 2 days of weekend in numer of days .
var d = new Date();
count = count + (parseInt(count/5))*2;
d.setDate(d.getDate() +count);
//suppose its ending on weekend day then increment them manually.
if(d.getDay()>5) {  d.setDate(d.getDate()+ (d.getDay()-5)) ; } 

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#txtFromDate").datepicker(
       { minDate: d, 
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true});
 });
```

Update: A bit more optimized.

Comment: this does not work if my count is 2 and the current day is friday (e.g. 12/11/2015). The answer should be 12/15/2015 (tuesday) but getting 12/13/2015 (Sunday)

Answer (score 4):

You can do the calculation manually and pass the next working day to the minDate like this.

```
// Calculate the next working day manually
    var startDate = new Date(),
    noOfDaysToAdd = 10,
    count = 1;

while(count <= noOfDaysToAdd){
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
    if(startDate.getDay() != 0 && startDate.getDay() != 6){
        count++;
    }
}

// Datepicker Init
$('#txtFromDate').datepicker({
    minDate: startDate,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Here is a working demo. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mfax3/5/)**

Comment: this works for me but still looking for solution not using loop